# How do I handle socket requests in separate threads, thread seems to be blocking main process

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, unix

I am trying to create a simple HTTP server in C++. I want each request to be handled simultaneously in separate threads, but when I create a thread and put a simple `sleep(10)` at the start to cause some delay, another request to the server cannot be made until the first thread finishes. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code so far:

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void send_response (int socket)
{
    sleep (10);

    char buffer[2048] = {0};

    int request = recv (socket, buffer, 2048, 0);

    if (request == -1) {
        perror ("error");
    }

    string message = "Hello from server";
    string length = to_string (message.length ());

    string hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Length: " + length + "\n\n" + message;

    send (socket, hello.c_str (), hello.length (), 0);

    close (socket);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof (address);

    int server_fd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (server_fd == 0) {
        perror ("socket failed");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt (server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof (opt))) {
        perror ("setsockopt");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons (8080);

    if (bind (server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)(&address), sizeof (address)) < 0) {
        perror ("bind failed");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen (server_fd, 3) < 0) {
        perror ("listen");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (true) {
        int new_socket = accept (server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)(&address), &addrlen);

        if (new_socket < 0) {
            perror ("accept");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        thread response (&send_response, new_socket);

        response.detach ();

        cout << "request handled" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't need to wait for the thread to finish or get any data back from the thread, I just want it to start, do some work, and send something back to the client. I expect each thread will be doing a decent amount of work, that's why I used sleep.

**Edit**: It seems the loop is ready and waiting for a second connection and will successfully accept a new connection and create a new thread to handle it, but only if the second connection is from a different IP address. So if I visit the server at 127.0.0.1:8080 and from a different local IP address like 192.168.1.91, both connections will go through with two threads running simultaneously. However, if I simply open two tabs, both at 127.0.0.1:8080, only one connection will be accepted at a time, the other will stall. It seems I need the code to handle multiple connections from the same IP address, but a search for that kind of problem on Google hasn't given me any good results.

Comment: ***I expect each thread will be doing a decent amount of work, that's why I used sleep*** what do you mean?

Comment: I think the issue, is the scope of the thread object - it's inside the while loop. So after one iteration, the object goes out of scope.

Comment: I mean that each thread will take a few seconds to finish, and I'd rather not have clients waiting just because one core on a 12 system is busy handling one request.

Comment: * 12 core system

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "object goes out of scope", does the loop scope affect the context the thread executes in? I've now tried adding the threads to a vector of threads, that made no difference.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought scope may affect but I was wrong there.

Comment: BTW, why do you provide address of send_response? Without that thread should accept the function.

Comment: You're right, the function doesn't need to be passed by address. I did it because the documentation says the first parameter is a "pointer to function, pointer to member, or any kind of move-constructible function object", so I passed the address. It doesn't make a difference to the code working or not, though.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and break while the second request is hanging? That should tell you what the main thread is up to.

Comment: Using gdb what command(s) should I use?

Comment: See my edit. I think I'm narrowing down the problem.

Comment: ***It seems I need the code to handle multiple connections from the same IP address,*** for that you may need different clients, try different browsers.

Comment: What does the other side look like, i.e. the client side? What did you do and observe which brought you to the conclusion that you present above?

Comment: The client side is a web browser (Chrome) and it just sits there loading for 10 seconds. If I open two tabs, the first tab loads for 10 seconds, the second tab loads for 20 seconds because it can only start the 10 second sleep after the first tab is finished. What I did was place a `cout` before and after the `accept` line in the loop, to see if the loop is still running with two tabs, and I observed that the loop runs only once with two tabs with the same IP, but runs twice with two tabs with different IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad, everything is working as expected. Using `wget` to send multiple requests from the same IP causes multiple threads to be created and for the requests to be processed simultaneously. In Chrome, for some reason opening multiple tabs from the same IP causes them to be sent in serial, but in Firefox they are sent in parallel and arrive and are processed at the same time. That is weird, but I'll chock it up to an oddity of Chrome.